# Mediawiki upload directory outside installation directory

Tags: mediawiki

I have installed Mediawiki in `/var/www/mediawiki/w`, where `/var/www/mediawiki` is the root directory. Is it possible to set the upload directory outside `w`, say `/var/www/mediawiki/images`, instead of a subdir of `w`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [wgUploadPath](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUploadPath) to a directory outside `w`